# How to divide polyline into 1-mile increments?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I have a river shapefile that I need to break up into 1-mile increments.

The polyline is 53 miles in distance, so I should I have about 53 mile markers as a result.

I have tried the Divide tool, but then it doesn't show if it did anything afterwards.

Should I manually use the Split tool to split the river at every mile increment, or is there a better way to do this?

I am creating a river mile map.

Comment: Which Divide tool did you try to do this with?  There seem to be several available so perhaps you can edit your Question to include a link to the online help for the one you used.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  I've seen references to a Divide tool elsewhere suggesting that it may no longer be part of the product.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should explore using **[Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000)** to display your mile markers.

If you need to physically break your rivers then I think Linear Referencing will be the way to do that too.

Comment: Could you expand on this? What functions in the linear referencing toolbox can be used to display mile markers?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach:

1. Use the "[Create Random Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002r000000)" tool with constraining feature class set to your polyline, minimum allowed distance set to the distance between line segments you want to split, and number of points set to something very large (the tool will be unable to create all of the points due to the specified minimum distance setting, and this will actually only create a point at your set intervals).
2. Use the "[Split Line at Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000)" tool with input features set to your original polyline and point features set to the output of the "Create Random Points" tool.

This should provide you with a polyline divided at whatever interval you'd like.