# "construct points" troubleshooting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, line

I need to create a series of points along a line at a specific interval. I am using ArcMap 10.2.1 and the obvious tool appears to be Construct Points.

I have tried to follow the instruction steps given on the ESRI website. However, the Edit tool on the editor toolbar is not selectable so have used Editor > Start Editing and selecting the line feature instead.

At no time is Construct Points selectable on the Editor drop-down menu even after trying various thing. What am I doing wrong?

Apologies for the potential simplicity of this problem but I just can't find a solution!

Comment: Have you got an empty point file in your MXD where the points can be saved? The tool won't be available otherwise.

Comment: Other approaches to this may be in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73078/how-to-divide-polyline-into-1-mile-increments - do you necessarily want an Editing solution or would a Geoprocessing tool or two be an as good or better solution?

Answer (score 3):

What I found is you have to select one line segment at a time.

My line layer had several segments (different rows in the attribute table) hence when I selected all the segments (all rows in attribute table) the Construct Points was greyed-out but when I selected one at a time, it worked.

Another way to get around this by doing it all at once is to first dissolve all the segments into one.