# Creating mile marker lines in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I need to create one mile increment dividers on a river system to separate out data. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: have you looked at this question and the answers suggested there? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73078/how-to-divide-polyline-into-1-mile-increments?rq=1. Specifically hatching in Linear referencing http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_hatching_route_feature_classes/00390000001n000000/.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ArcGIS 10 compatible python script which will convert a polyline to spaced points](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e19b53170e004e46827b8129d6ef9bfe).  Using this you could create a point along the river line spaced at 1 mile intervals - would that do?

You could also do it manually using the "densify" tool, using the distance parameter, followed by "convert polyline to points" based on the vertices created by the densify tool.